# How to install Rekonq 1.0 on Fedora 17?

Tags: fedora, kde, software-installation

I would like to install Rekonq 1.0 on Fedora 17, using KDE 4.8.5.

At the moment, this version of Rekonq isn't available in the repositories, I have  version 0.9.2. Anyone knows how can I update my app?

Answer (score 1):

You can build it from the Fedora 18 source rpm here http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/rekonq/1.0/1.fc18/src/rekonq-1.0-1.fc18.src.rpm

rpmbuild --rebuild rekonq-1.0-1.fc18.src.rpm

all the required dependencies are in the standard f17 repos (qca2-devel and qoauth-devel)

Comment: I need kdelibs4-devel. Where I can download it?

Answer (score 0):

You could build it yourself, using a SRPM (e.g. [this one](http://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/rekonq/0.9.2/1.fc17/src/rekonq-0.9.2-1.fc17.src.rpm)) as a starting point (just adapt it for rekonq 1.0).

Seems that Rekonq 1.0 will be avaliable on Fedora 18: [the RPM for that](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=340777) **might** work but probably will have dependency problems.